# How do you set the default source for the Output window in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010, output-window

We added a SharePoint BDC model project to a solution in Visual Studio 2010.  Ever since, whenever the solution is built, instead of showing the Build output in the Output window, it insists on having "SharePoint Tools" selected in the "Show Output from:" drop-down, just to say "Model validation started ...  Model validation completed with no errors."

Short of shutting off any SharePoint projects in the build configuration, can this behavior be overridden?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a bug in the SharePoint tools. I recommend you report it.